# Is there a minimum height locked on inline-block span?

Tags: css

I was charged with making printed ID cards (hence why I work with cm and pt units) and I need text to be very small in order for it to work.

The only aces I have is css, I can't change the HTML, the content is loaded from a database. **When I make the font-size any smaller than 12pt, the span stops getting smaller or more accurately it stops getting closer together.** I can't make the span position relative because some titles are too long to fit one line (that's why I need the text to be so small) so it need to be position relative.

**What's the way I can get the span to get closer together without making then position:absolute**

I've made an example for you to see (the animation is only to show how the height of the span stops shrinking with the text):

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#container, span{
  width:7.5cm;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5cm 0;
}
#container{
  background:grey;
  height:10cm;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: normal;
  height: auto;
  max-height: none;
  padding: 0cm 1.2cm;  
}
.name{
  font-size:12pt;
  line-height:initial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  position: relative;
  top: initial;
  /*margin-top: 6.87cm;*/
  margin-bottom:0.05cm;
}
.title{
  font-size:5pt;
  line-height:initial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top:0.05cm;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: moving;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
.role{
  font-size:7pt;
  line-height:initial;
}
@keyframes moving {
    0% {
        font-size: 5pt;
    }
    50% {
        font-size: 15pt;
    }
    100% {
        font-size: 5pt;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="name">Name</span>
  <span class="title">Title 1</span>
  <span class="role">Role 1</span>
  <span class="title">Title 2</span>
  <span class="role">Role 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: it's about line-height here ...use for example `line-height:1pt` on container and you will see the difference

Comment: Nice animation tough ;D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `line-height` of the container to 0:

```css
body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#container, span{
  width:7.5cm;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5cm 0;
}
#container{
  background:grey;
  line-height: 0;
  height:10cm;
}
span{
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: normal;
  height: auto;
  max-height: none;
  padding: 0cm 1.2cm;  
}
.name{
  font-size:12pt;
  line-height:initial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  position: relative;
  top: initial;
  margin-top: 6.87cm;
  margin-bottom:0.05cm;
}
.title{
  font-size:5pt;
  line-height:initial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top:0.05cm;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: moving;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
.role{
  font-size:7pt;
  line-height:initial;
}
@keyframes moving {
    0% {
        font-size: 5pt;
    }
    50% {
        font-size: 15pt;
    }
    100% {
        font-size: 5pt;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="name">Name</span>
  <span class="title">Title 1</span>
  <span class="role">Role 1</span>
  <span class="title">Title 2</span>
  <span class="role">Role 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Great kudos to you sir!